# Hide the parameter hints

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I am writing on vscode,

there's constantly parameter hints which is annoying especially when the codes hits the bottom.

How could I hide them?

[image]

Comment: It's no code but it's so annoying that I'm gonna upvote. hate auto suggest that are not variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add next property to settings object in `File > Preferences > Settings`  `User settings` (right tab):

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": false
```

After that, if you want to see hint when typing - press `ctrl+space` to open it and `Esc` - to close.

Comment: And also I read that "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false property may help to some similar situations also.